# Sub menu moves when changing padding

Tags: css, styles

I have a Prestashop with a CSS menu, http://empk.dk/nyshop/ the padding is now: 15px 9px 15px in this #header `.pt_custommenu` `.pt_menu`

Before I changed it, it was 11px 9px 37px, and it worked before, but now, the sub menu doesn't align with the main menu, I've tried to look in the chrome debug mode, and in the CSS file, but I just can't find the issue or what code to edit.

I assume it's in the div called popup, but I can't find it.

You can see the CSS file here: http://empk.dk/nyshop/themes/pos_elly5/modules/posmegamenu/css/custommenu.css

The menu I want to edit is the "beige" / yellow colored.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

".popup" Class having css property through the Jquery or inline style so you need to find this class and apply "top:53px" on that class

or

just write in your css this Class :

```
.popup{
  top:52px !important;
}
```

but when you use the "!important" keyword at that time you need to be very careful that it affects others class or not.